# Foreach array returning empty but shows desired response within loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to scrape all of these urls and pass them into my database but when I return the response of the foreach loop I get an empty array.

The mind boggling part for me is that when I console.log the desired return value(allUrlsOnSite) within the foreach loop I get the response I am looking for:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/quWic.png

I feel like I am missing something fundamental to how promises operate.

Thank you for your time.

```
async function scrapeAllLinksOffPage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let x = Xray()

    x(url, 'div', [

        'a@href'
      ])
      .paginate('a@href')
      .limit(0)
      .then(function (storeScrapes) {
        let arrOfUrls = uniq(storeScrapes);
        // console.log(arrOfUrls);
        return resolve(arrOfUrls);
      })
    if (false) {
      return reject("failed")
    }

  });
};

async function consolidateLinksInOneArray(...arr) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let urlsPayload = arr[0];
    let allUrlsOnSite = [];
    urlsPayload.forEach(url => {
      scrapeAllLinksOffPage(url).then(res => {
        let arrOfUrls = res;
        allUrlsOnSite = allUrlsOnSite.concat(arrOfUrls);
        uniq(allUrlsOnSite);
         console.log(allUrlsOnSite);
      })
      return resolve(allUrlsOnSite);
    })
    if (false) {
      return reject("failed")
    }

  });

}

scrapeAllLinksOffPage('https://google.com/').then(res => {
  let arrOfUrls = res;
  //  console.log(arrOfUrls);
  consolidateLinksInOneArray(arrOfUrls).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
})
```

Comment: You are looking for `.map` instead of `.forEach`

Comment: `async` + `return new Promise` is an anti-pattern. You're wrapping a promise in a promise.